# why is the wrong "case" being executed after "default" in a switch statement

Tags: java

How is it possible that the output is 1002,why is the last case being executed despite having a mismatch?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0,j=0;
        switch (i) {
            case 2 : j++;
            default: j+=2;
            case 15 : j+=1000;
        }
        System.out.println("j="+j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FALLTHROUGH:

> Another point of interest is the break statement. Each break statement
>   terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with
>   the first statement following the switch block. The break statements
>   are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall
>   through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in
>   sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels,
>   until a break statement is encountered.

Your code should be:

```
  case 2 : j++; break;
  case 4:  j+=10; break;
  default: j+=2; break;
  case 15: j+=1000;
}
```

[`FROM DOCS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

```
public class Example{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.ArrayList<String> futureMonths =
        new java.util.ArrayList<String>();

    int month = 8;

    switch (month) {
        case 1:  futureMonths.add("January");
        case 2:  futureMonths.add("February");
        case 3:  futureMonths.add("March");
        case 4:  futureMonths.add("April");
        case 5:  futureMonths.add("May");
        case 6:  futureMonths.add("June");
        case 7:  futureMonths.add("July");
        case 8:  futureMonths.add("August");
        case 9:  futureMonths.add("September");
        case 10: futureMonths.add("October");
        case 11: futureMonths.add("November");
        case 12: futureMonths.add("December");
        default: break;
    }

    if (futureMonths.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid month number");
    } else {
        for (String monthName : futureMonths) {
           System.out.println(monthName);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
This is the output from the code:

August
September
October
November
December
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to break at the end of the case blocks. Otherwise all subsequent cases will be also executed.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    int i=0,j=0;
    switch (i){
        case 2 : j++; break;
        case 4: j+=10; break;
        case 15 : j+=1000; break;
        default: j+=2;
    }
    System.out.println("j="+j);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing `break;`

and if I understand your confusion, The order of default doesn't matter. In below case,

```
    int i=15,j=0;
    switch (i){
        case 2 : 
            j++;
            break;
        case 4: 
            j+=10;
            break;
        default: 
            j+=2;
            break;
        case 15 : 
            j+=1000;
            break;
    }
```

`j` will be having value `1000` even if `default` was before `case 15`

Answer (score -1):

you don't have the 'break' keyword specified in each of your cases.

Should be like this:

```
switch (i){
    case 2 : 
    j++;
    break;
    case 4:
    j+=10;
    break;
    case 15 : 
    j+=1000;
    break;
    default: 
    j+=2;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case case 2 and case 4 are not execute but default and case 15 are so the answer is 1002. Please put break statement for desired result.

Hope this helps.